# Is char str1[] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'} copied from constants memory segment to stack like char str2[] = "string"?

Tags: c, string, memory, stack, string-literals

I know that in case one uses the next syntax `char str1[] = "string"`, "string" is saved in constants segment and is copied to the stack (`printf("%p", str1)` shows stack's address). I wish to know whether `char str2[] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'}` is subjected to the same process as `char str1[] = "string"`, or is just saved in stack (`printf("%p", str2)` shows stack's address) .

Comment: The *stack* thing *may be* true only if it is a local definition. The initializer does not have to be copied into constants section, it can be very well hardcoded into the initialization code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The side effects of these declarations

```
char str2[] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};
```

and

```
char str1[] = "string";
```

are different.

Pay attention to that the last initialization could be written for example like

```
char str1[] = "str" "ing";
```

In the last case (the C Standard, 6.4.5 String literals)

> 6 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
>   each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
>   or literals.78) **The multibyte character sequence is then used to
>   initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufﬁcient to contain the sequence...**

In the first case neither character array with the static storage duration is created from the separate characters used as initializers.

Comment: The question implies that we are talking about automatic storage array rather than static.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am talking about string literals. It is unimportant what kind of array is initialized by a string literal.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to apply this citation to the case, but neither of ways are causing any static storage array to be defined in this example: https://godbolt.org/z/AtW_eR Both initializers are hardcoded.

Comment: @EugeneSh. According to the quote an array with a string literal is created with the static storage duration.

Comment: @cremno Well, 32 is an exact answer to this question, and it is contradicting this answer. (Here is the link for completeness: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p32)

Comment: @cremno The p/#14 does not contradict the quote I provided. The array is created at translation phase 7 before any string literal is used to initialize an array. Moreover see the declaration that I showed in my answer.

Comment: I suppose the static storage for a string literal used to initialize a `char[]` doesn't need to be emitted due to the "as-if" rule. Are there any actual implementations that store both the string literal and the the initializer?

Comment: @IanAbbott The initializer is usually stored if sufficiently long to be hardcoded (it has to be copied in runtime for automatic variables - you can modify my examples for longer strings to see). But it is true for any type of initializer.

Comment: Anyhow, according to http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p32 the definitions in the question are identical from the language point of view.

Comment: I see. So strictly according to the standard with a string literal there has to be an object with static storage duration but the storage duration of the members of the initializer list isn't required to be static (even if it's the case for longer ones and decent implementations). Your answer sorta implies a practical difference which surprised me.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That wasn't quite what I meant, but I now think my comment was ill-considered. I was thinking the compiler has to store the initializer somewhere (at least for objects of static storage duration), but it wouldn't need to store the string literal because it was just being used as syntactic sugar for initializing a `char[]`. But it never occurred to me that the storage for the initializer and the string literal could overlap in the same way that storage for identical string literals can overlap.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment about using a string literal as an initializer being "syntactic sugar", that is not really the case for string literals containing multi-byte character sequences. In that case, initializing the `char[]` byte-by-byte would require knowledge of the multi-byte encoding rules, which would make the code less portable (and would also be a PITA).

Comment: (a) Neither of the declarations has side effects as defined in the C standard. (b) Although the declarations are different purely within the abstract model defined by the C standard in that the first sets the initial values from the listed values and the second defines an array with static storage duration that is then used to set the initial values, this difference is purely abstract and should have no effect in a decent compiler…

Comment: … In practice, the declarations are identical: In both cases, the compiler must store the initial values somewhere—could be static storage, could be built into instruction immediates, could be optimized into the code depending on context—and must initialize the array from those initial values when the array is completed. If the array is defined in a context where it has automatic storage duration and is instantiated on the stack (e.g., not optimized away), this initialization has identical requirements for the two declarations.